# building MobileVLC -> armc7 + ffmpeg issue

Tags: xcode, ffmpeg, vlc, armv7

I'm trying to build MobileVLC on OS X Lion, against iOS SDK 5.0. So far, no dice.

Followed the given instructions, however, build stops and fails here: 
[info] Building contrib for iOS in '/Users/shamil/Documents/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib-builddir-ios-i686-apple-darwin10

Current log:
./buildMobileVLC.sh -s
[info] Preparing build dirs
[info] Building
[info] Building vlc
[info] Building libvlc for the iOS
[info] Using i386 with SDK version 4.2
[info] Building contrib for iOS in '/Users/shamil/Documents/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib-builddir-ios-i686-apple-darwin10'

The error is given as follows:

```
make[1]: *** [.ffmpeg] Error 1
make: *** [using-src] Error 2
```

/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib-builddir-ios-arm-apple-darwin10/build-src/ffmpeg/config.log tells me:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option 'L/Users/shamil/Documents/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib-ios-arm-apple-darwin10/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/shamil/Documents/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib-ios-arm-apple-darwin10/lib'
**ld: in /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib, missing required architecture armv7 in file for architecture armv7**
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
C compiler test failed.
```

I've bolded the one which I think is causing it to fail. Now - how do I fix THIS error?

Comment: Im having the exact same problem. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Nope :( Still scouring for answers

Answer (score 1):

Add "-L$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/system" to LDFLAGS variable.

Where SDKROOT is the directory that points to the latest iOS.

e.g: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk

Comment: Hello, where is LDFLAGS variable?

Answer (score 1):

This got it to work for me:

> ./configure
>   --extra-ldflags=-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents//Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system
>   --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm --target-os=darwin --cc='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc
>   -arch armv7' --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk
>   --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-pic --extra-ldflags='-arch armv7'

Comment: this worked for me, thanks!, I'm gonna try it out with armv7s